# Why do we need an interface to be declared inside class? Do we have any advantage by doing so?

Tags: java, android

I have an interface ForumApi inside class ForumService. I am using Retrofit and Rxjava here.Usually for Retrofit,we implement an interface but in the below code i see the interface inside the class.is there any specific reason for this?

```
public class ForumService {

    public interface ForumApi {

        @GET("/posts")
        public Observable<List<Post>>
            getPosts();

        @GET("/posts/{id}")
        public Observable<Post>
            getPost(@Path("id") int postId);

        @GET("/comments")
        public Observable<List<Comment>>
            getComments(@Query("postId") int postId);

        @POST("/posts")
        public Observable<Post>
            postPost(Post post);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If an interface `A` is intended to be used by a specific class/interface `B` then it makes sense to tie them together by declaring `A` inside `B`.

Another such example is the interface `Map.Entry` which is declared inside the `Map` interface (e.g. you are not supposed to use `Map.Entry` inside a `List`).

Comment: I must disagree here. If interface `A` is intended to be used by specific class `B`, but `A` related to networking and `B` contains business logic, then they definitely shouldn't be declared in the same file. I would say even not in the same package.

Comment: @Vasiliy thanks for taking it a step further, but I can't think of a use-case such as you describe. An example would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "use-case". IMHO any class that combines business rules and networking related rules violates Single Responsibility Principle and should be refactored. Preferably into different packages.

Comment: @Vasiliy by use-case I mean a concrete example, such as `Map.Entry` given in this answer. An example of an interface which is intended for use by a specific class yet declared elsewhere due to unrelated business logic.

Comment: In my application I have reverse geocoder that sends network requests. This networking is also handled by Retrofit. Even though the only client of this API is reverse geocoder, interface's definition resides in "networking" package. Source: https://github.com/techyourchance/idocare-android

Comment: @Vasiliy thanks for the example, I see your point. It all boils down to code style: those who like this approach like it because it makes a statement that this interface should be used by this class only and as a (good) side-effect they get a more concise package (one less file). Those who don't like this approach consider SRP to be more important and can also (justifiably) claim that today only one class uses the interface but we can't foresee the future. Neither sides is either "right" or "wrong", it's just a matter of personal preferences.

Comment: I think I might burn in hell if I agree that one class less is a valid justification for SRP violation, but the good thing about our business is that you're fine as long as you know what you're doing )

Comment: @Vasiliy as a side-note, the fact that you have strong feelings about having a code clean - is a good indicator: it means that you **care**. This is one of the most important characters that makes a good engineer. Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is a non-optimal design decision.

There are some valid use-cases for inner interfaces. For example: in implementation of Observable design pattern, if there is one-to-one correspondence between Observer and Observable, it is a widespread practice to declare Observer's interface (listener) as an inner interface inside Observable.

This is not the case in your code.

I don't know what `ForumService` does, but I guess that it contains some business logic related to forum management. If this is the case, then, according to Single Responsibility Principle, `ForumService` and `ForumApi` shouldn't be declared in the same class.

I will also go as far as saying that they shouldn't be defined in the same package. All networking related classes should reside in a separate package that contains networking stuff only.

In addition, in this case, the interface itself contains implementation details - Retrofit's annotations. By placing this interface inside `ForumService`, the design effectively makes `ForumService` depend on Retrofit. This is less important, but still valid reason for refactoring this interface out of the class.